# laravel 5.7 Error: Call to a member function save() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

i'm using Laravel Framework 5.7.25
i'm trying to create a post by current user who has already logged in.
but i'm facing these Errors:

> Call to a member function save() on null
>   [this is Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuOiQ.png)
>   this is my PostController :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->body=$request['body'];
        $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

and this is Post model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

and this is User model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
 use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
  public function posts()
  {
      $this->hasMany('App\Post');
  }
}
```

Comment: return $this->hasMany

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `user()` and `posts()` relationships aren't returning anything:

```
public function posts() {
    $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

needs to become:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

and the same tweak made for `user()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your code slightly, this should work:

```php
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->posts()->create($request->only('body'));

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```